# Is $x^3+nx+1$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ for infinitely many $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then is $x^3+nx+1$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ for infinitely many $n$?

Answer (score 0):

That polynomial is reducible if and only if it has a rational root. But, by the rational root theorem, the only possible roots of that polynomial are $\pm1$. And it is clear that, unless $n$ is small, none of these numbers is a root of that polynomial.